# Retrieve the saved location of the android-sdk from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

**Is there a way to get the saved location of the "android-sdk" within eclipse?**

If you go to `window -> preferences -> android`. There is a text field containing the location of the android-sdk. Is there a way to query `eclipse` for that value in an `ANT` script or by other means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Mac, I found the value in a file stored in my workspace:
{workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.prefs

File contents:

```
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.fixLegacyEditors=1
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.sdk=/Users/Jakuben/Documents/android_dev_environment/android-sdk-macosx
eclipse.preferences.version=1
```